# multiple tables on same line

Tags: html, css

I have three tables that are all contained in a div. I am trying to get them to all show inline in the div, but they each show on their own line. I set them all to display: inline at the table level, but this didn't do the trick. Any ideas of how to get multiple tables to show on the same line?

```
 <div id="container">
   <table id="previous-arrow" class="scroll">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="nav-prev"><span>Previous</span></a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table id="tour-carousel">
    <tr id="carousel-row">
        <td>data here</td> 
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table id="next-arrow" class="scroll">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="nav-next"><span>Next</span></a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: something like `floating : left` maybe?

Answer (score 18):

You want to make them display inline, but still as tables (otherwise their content will create anonymous table blocks which cause wrapping).

```
display: inline-table;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can float them:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <table><tr><td>Table 1</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>Table 2</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>Table 3</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
table {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/6HuyW/

Comment: I tried this, but it still goes on multiple lines. Perhaps other css issues are crowding in.

Comment: Can you post your CSS above too?

Answer (score 1):

Try to float them left in the css.

```
table {
 float:left;
}
```

And make sure the width's of them side-by-side isn't greater than that of there container.

Answer (score 0):

USE BELOW CODE

```
<div id="container">
   <table id="previous-arrow" class="scroll" **style="float:left"**>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" id="nav-prev"><span>Previous</span></a></td>
</tr>
 </table>
<table id="tour-carousel" **style="float:left"**>
<tr id="carousel-row">
    <td>data here</td> 
</tr>
</table>
<table id="next-arrow" class="scroll" **style="float:left"**>
<tr>
    <td><a href="#" id="nav-next"><span>Next</span></a></td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```